# can load up the model with existing urn ?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Here is the snapshot of the [lmvquickstart](http://developer-autodesk.github.io/LmvQuickStart/), i got a encoded urn of the translated file.

[image]

I used that urn to load the model in html but got a failure

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var viewerApp;
        var options = {
            env: 'AutodeskProduction',
            accessToken: 'YOUR ACCESS TOKEN'
        };

        var documentId = 'YOUR BASE 64 ENCODED URN';

        $.getJSON( 'http://'+window.location.host+ "/v1/models", function( data ) {
            console.log(data);

            options.accessToken = data.accessToken;
            documentId = data.urn;

            // documentId = urn:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Y29udHJvbGxlci9MRUQlMjB2MS5zdGVw

            console.log(options.accessToken, documentId);

            Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized(){
                viewerApp = new Autodesk.A360ViewingApplication('viewer');
                viewerApp.registerViewer(viewerApp.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D);
                viewerApp.loadDocumentWithItemAndObject(documentId);
            });

        });

});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like one of the reasons can be, your translated URN has expired, the model was probably uploaded to a Transient bucket, meaning it will expire after 24 hours since the translation was done. I would try using a temporary one for now which will keep your model translation for 30 days.

I'm going to leave a couple of links that can help you out with the start of your development.

https://github.com/jaimerosales/nodejs-forge-viewer-tutorial

Comment: Hi,Jaime, I have used http://developer-autodesk.github.io/LmvQuickStart/ to upload my model, it looks the uploading and translation is successful but still new generated urn doesn't work for me. Is there a other web interface for uploading my model for the testing purpsose

Comment: That website hasn't been updated in quite a while, if you want to translate models to get back a urn, use models.autodesk.io

Comment: Thanks, jaime, models.autodesk.io works great for me 1!

Comment: Hi,Jaimi, another question,  for a big model composed of many small stl.file, should I put them into a big stl file and upload the single model or should I upload each individual stl and display all these models at a single page simultaneously?

Comment: So using the model derivative api you could upload it with references, but I will try it as a full stl file with all the ones you need to be in. Try it and let me know